# how can i check if files exist for the given list of paths?

Tags: java, file, file-io, guava

I have a list of 50,000 paths and I need to check if a file exists against each of these paths. Right now, I am verifying each path independently like this:

```
public static List<String> filesExist(String baseDirectory, Iterable<String> paths) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File directory = new File(baseDirectory);
        if(!directory.exists()){
            throw new FileNotFoundException("No Directory found: " + baseDirectory );
        }else{
            if(!directory.isDirectory())
                throw new FileNotFoundException(baseDirectory + " is not a directory!");
        }

        List<String> filesNotFound = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String path : paths) {
            if(!new File(baseDirectory + path).isFile())
                filesNotFound.add(path);
        }
        return filesNotFound;
    }
```

Is there a way to improve it so that I don't create 50,000 File objects ? I am also using guava. Is there any utility in there which can help me with bulk `exists()` method ?

Comment: Creating 50000 objects is not the slowest part of this, disk access is. I don't think you can do better than this, short of breaking out JNI.

Comment: Are you sure you need this FileNotFoundException? I thought that was the goal of your method - to check the file existence. I mean, it's "programming on exceptions".

Comment: @iozee throwing an exception if the directory itself is not found. I'd expect baseDirectory to be atleast present for me to search within that directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The creation of 50,000 `File` objects is almost certainly not the bottleneck. The actual filesystem operations is probably what's making it slow.

I have two suggestions:

1. Before checking, sort paths by their location to make best use of filesystem caches.
2. If a sub-directory does not exist, you can automatically assume that all files and sub-directories therein don't exist either.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer from aix, but I would like to add one point of view. Assuming that filesystem access is the bottleneck and **IF** the number of files under baseDirectory is roughly known and not too huge (whatever that means), it could be worth trying out `FileUtils.iterateFiles` or `FileUtils.listFiles`, and then check for each returned path if it exists in paths. The idea behind this is that it's possible that the directory listing that these methods perform are more efficient than many separate accesses.

Again, this approach depends on a number of assumptions about your environment, but it's always worth giving it a thought and try it out.

(Wanted to add this as a comment to aix's reply, but couldn't...)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO a very efficient solution (inspired by both previous answers) goes as follows:

- sort the paths
- consider each of them as tree
- the other tree is the directory tree
- when accessing the directory tree read whole directories in case there are "many" children in the other tree, otherwise use separate checks the "few" children
- do a parallel traversal of both trees skipping parts missing in one of them

Example (trees given as preorder list):

```
tree1: / /a /a/a /d /d/a /d/a/b /e
tree2: / /a /b /d /d/a /e
```

Processing:

- Start with `/`
- descend into `/a` since present in both
- skip `/a/a` as missing in tree2
- skip `/b` as missing in tree1
- descend into `/d` since present in both
- ...

Your `filesNotFound` list consists of all the files skipped in the tree corresponding with the input list.

Answer (score 0):

I can't start my development environment right now because of reasons, so this might be slightly incorrect. Go-go gadget functional programming!

```
public static List<String> filesExist(String baseDirectory, Iterable<String> paths) throws FileNotFoundException{
    final File base = new File(baseDirectory);
    if (base.exists()) {
        return FluentIterable.from(paths).filter(new Predicate<String>() {
            public boolean apply(String in) {
                return new File(in,base).exists();
            }
        }).toImmutableList();
    }
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Base doesn't exist!");
}
```

As said above, your major issue will still be I/O.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a special data structure for this.

[TRIE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

[image]

Think your terminal nodes as files and parent of them containing folder. You can check your folder for terminal nodes. It will dramatically reduce the amount of the seek operation if some of the files share same parent.

And your total operation count will be

Total Operation = Total Node - Terminal Nodes

And simple traversal algorithm your special tree would be enough for it. Sorry but strongly believe that this solution is not based on Guava but would fit better.